# How can I add a node to the selected node in a TreeView?

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I create a treeview with several nodes in a WinForms application. I want to add a node to one of this nodes (to a child node).

How do I can do this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every Node in treeview(winforms) is having a collection of Nodes so if you got to the node reference than just adding a new node under its collection will do the job

```
TreeNode node = treeView.SelectedNode;
node.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   // Add a root TreeNode for each Customer object in the ArrayList.
   foreach(Customer customer2 in customerArray)
   {
      treeView1.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(customer2.CustomerName));

      // Add a child treenode for each Order object in the current Customer object.
      foreach(Order order1 in customer2.CustomerOrders)
      {
         treeView1.Nodes[customerArray.IndexOf(customer2)].Nodes.Add(
           new TreeNode(customer2.CustomerName + "." + order1.OrderID));
      }
   }
```

Entire sample on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.nodes.aspx)...

Answer (score 1):

By simply using the `Add` method of the `Node` collection of a [TreeNode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bctbxtcb%28v=VS.71%29.aspx)

ie.

```
treeNode.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode("Node Name"));
```